# Blazor Server-Side: Show file in razor page that is outside wwwroot folder

Tags: pdf, razor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have a PDF file in a folder called "UploadedFiles". This folder is not inside the wwwroot folder.

On the "showFile.razor" page I want to show this PDF.

How can I return the PDF file from UploadedFiles to showFile.razor

I used  element on the showFile.razor page with the file in wwwroot and it worked, but the file is accessible for everyone when it is in wwwroot. This is not what I desire.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-file-authorization)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Can you give me an example? I have a razor page ShowFile.razor and a folder in the root of my project (outside wwwroot) called StaticFiles. How can I return a file from this folder to my razor page and display it? (pdf / png / jpeg / docx)

Comment: With https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-file-authorization the entire project will use RequireAuthenticatedUser.